# Time components separate from other in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

C and I'm working on a speaking clock. My problem is that I can save the time (hour and minute) in two `NSInteger`s but I can't compare them.

The concrete problem is that I want to separate the time (for example the hour is stored in the `NSInteger` like this: `16`. I want to get a `1` and a `6` separately). I want to separate one digit from the other digit to compare them.

Can anybody help me? A good compare syntax also will be a big help! Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your question for readability. Please take the time to type your questions with proper punctuation, spelling, grammar, and spacing. The computer won't run your code if it can't read it, and your fellow humans don't like answering your questions if they can't read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your request, you want to separate the the whole number into digits from 0-9?

you could do it like this:

```
int hours = 16
int hour1 = hours / 10;
int hour2 = hours - hour1
hour2     = hours % 10;

int minutes = 47;
int minute1 = minutes / 10;
int minute2 = minutes - minute1;
minute2 = minutes % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `div` function for this purpose (for `NSInteger`, use [`ldiv`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ldiv.3.html)):

```
ldiv_t q;
NSInteger hours = 16;
q = ldiv(hours, 10);
NSInteger hours_tens_digit = q.quot;
NSInteger hours_minutes_digit = q.rem;
```

Update: As amattn pointed out in a comment, `NSInteger` on iOS is 32-bit, so you can use either `div` or `ldiv`. (Using standard library functions that are typed like this is, of course, one of the situations when `NSInteger` suddenly becomes much less useful.)

Comment: I think you can use div or ldiv for iOS (both int and long are 32bits).

Comment: @amattn: Are you sure? In the [Foundation Data Types doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16) it looks like it's always 64-bit. (I may be wrong; I haven't done much on iOS -- I always forget to look for the [iPhone] tags on questions, darn it.)

Comment: yup.  sizeof(long) == 4 in iOS...  (i always forget to look for the non-iphone tags...)